# Laravel Jensenggers Eloquent Model sort main model with relation model

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb, eloquent

I'm trying to sort entire dataset of main model through column of relational model. I am using **Laravel ORM 5.2.43** and **Jensenggers MongoDb 3.1**

Here are the models I have

**UserEventActivity.php** - Mongo Model

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class UserEventActivity extends Eloquent 
{

    protected $collection = 'user_event_activity';
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    public function handset() {

        return $this->hasOne('HandsetDetails', '_id', 'handset_id');
    }

    public function storeDetail() {

        return $this->hasOne('StoreDetails', 'st_id', 'store_id');
    }

}
```

**HandsetDetails.php** - Mongo Model

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class HandsetDetails extends Eloquent 
{

    var $collection = 'user_handset_details';
    var $connection = 'mongodb';

}
```

**StoreDetails.php** - MySql Model

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class StoreDetails extends Eloquent 
{

    use HybridRelations;

    protected $connection = 'mysql';
    protected $table = 'icn_store';

}
```

**Php script**

```
$activity = UserEventActivity::join('handset ', 'handset._id', '=', 'handset_id')
    ->join('storeDetail', 'store_id', '=', 'storeDetail.st_id')
    ->orderBy('handset.handset_make', 'desc')
    ->select('storeDetail.*', 'handset.*')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

This data from `UserEventActivity` is not stored based on `handset_make` field in handset relation.

Please help me to achieve the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know MongoDB does not support joins like this.

A way around it could be to use eager loading.

So your `UserEventActivity` model might look like this:

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class UserEventActivity extends Eloquent 
{

    protected $collection = 'user_event_activity';
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    public function handset() {

        return $this->hasOne('HandsetDetails', '_id', 'handset_id');
    }

    public function storeDetail() {

        return $this->hasOne('StoreDetails', 'st_id', 'store_id');
    }

    public function getHandsetMakeAttribute()
    {
        return $this->handset->handset_make;
    }


}
```

Note the `getHandsetMakeAttribute()` accessor. 
Then you may be able to make your call with this:

```
$activity = UserEventActivity::with('storeDetail')
    ->with('handset')
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc('handset_make')
    ->toArray();
```

Not at all tested but worth a go.

Comment: This is actually fetching ALL the entries from the database, and ordering it on PHP side.
This will not work if you have pagination for instance ...